# Intel GMA 965 M - OpenGL missing

Tags: windows-7, drivers, vga, opengl, intel-gma

I have a Lenovo 3000 N200 notebook with integrated GMA 965 VGA, using Windows 7.

All my drivers are up to date, downloaded directly from the vendor site, installed with administrative privileges, etc.

Yet, all OpenGL applications cannot render the interface (or any visuals). Examples are [Blender](http://blender.org) (3D modeling software) and [Babo Violent](http://rndlabs.ca) (top-down FPS).

All the controls, sound effects and music are live, but the screen is black or light gray, respectively.

What can one do?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/resultsForProduct.aspx?displaylang=en&productID=9C954C37-1ED1-4846-8A7D-85FC422D1388 < Did you try?

Comment: @Shiki Can you tell me why you're asking OP to update DirectX files when his OpenGL applications aren't working ?

Comment: Had some problems like this and this seemingly fixed them. Just an idea and it won't hurt to update them. :) Just an idea/note/comment.

Comment: @Shiki Oh Ok. Gotcha.

Comment: @Shiki, updated DirectX, was no use. Thank you for the tip. Any other guesses, please?

Comment: Try checking BIOS. You can adjust the amount of ram and so on there. Try giving more ram to the dedicated vga. (Sorry no other idea but hope something will come to my mind)

Comment: @Shiki, I have a very basic Phoenix BIOS that allows me to set boot order only. (Koszonom a segitseget ettol fuggetlenul. ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe this happened. Although you might expect someone giving me the advice to turn Windows Aero **off**, the actual resolution for this problem was to **turn it on**.

Comment: Hah no comment. Actually it gives a lot more headache for me if I turn it on. :/

Comment: You tell me. I want the basic theme back!!11

Comment: Damn... I can't believe but this is the actual solution. I found it finally.